# Sending mail directly from a form

Tags: php, email

I have an Contact us page on my website. what i want is when someone fills the form and click on send button. The message should be arrived to my gmail. i wrote the following code for it. its not working. is there any other way i can accomplish the same.

Html code:

```
<form id="ContactForm" action="contacts.php" method="post">
    <div>
        <div  class="wrapper"> <strong>Name:</strong>
            <div class="bg">
                <input type="text" class="input" name="name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div  class="wrapper"> <strong>Email:</strong>
            <div class="bg">
                <input type="text" class="input" name="email">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div  class="textarea_box"> <strong>Message:</strong>
            <div class="bg">
                <textarea cols="1" rows="1" name="message"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="document.getElementById('ContactForm').submit();" class="button"><span>Send</span></a> <a href="#" class="button"><span>Clear</span></a> </div>
          </form>
```

php code

```
<?php
session_start();
$to = "someemail@gmail.com";
$subject = "Someone Tried to contact you";
$message = $_POST['message'];
$fromemail = $_POST['email'];
$fromname = $_POST['name'];
$lt= '<';
$gt= '>';
$sp= ' ';
$from= 'From:';
$headers = $from.$fromname.$sp.$lt.$fromemail.$gt;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "mail sent";
exit();
?>
```

Comment: Hi! I am [Bobby tables'](http://xkcd.com/327/) little brother. You may call me `Johny\r\nHeader: Injection`.

Comment: How's the mail server configured? Are you trying the script in your local computer or in a server. I'd look into that first.

Comment: I uploaded all this in a webserver. not local computer. its not working

Comment: can anyone tell me what other solutions i have to do this

Comment: Missing ending semi-colon, for one thing. Google "php form validation" you'll find a lot of examples way better than this. And if that's your way to prevent someone hacking your code, I'm sorry to say but it won't work.

Comment: You code has errors. Fix that first.

Comment: Fixed it. and its working now. i know this solution is not good. can anyone suggest me a better solution?

Comment: Are you *trying* to send via SMTP? If so, you have to set it up on your web server first. If you're using your own email for your website, you need to add an SPF record

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should check your inputs for PHP injection.

```
$message = stripslashes($_POST['message']);
$fromemail = stripslashes($_POST['email']);
$fromname = stripslashes($_POST['name']);
```

Apart from that, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your mail script. The problem is most likely caused from your PHP server. Does your web hosting definitely provide PHP mail? Most free web hosts do not provide this as they are often used for spamming.

Comment: its working. i made some correction. is there any other way to send mail directly to my gmail using an contact us form

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but your code is crappy (especially, those concatenations). Use [Swift mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) which provides OOP-style and does all the header job for you. And make sure you've got any mail server installed (did you check if you have any?).

Comment: i have mail server installed. i am sure about it

Answer (score 0):

PHP form:

```
<?php

header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );

// Your Email
$receiver = 'max.mustermann@domain.tld';


if (isset($_POST['send']))
{






    $name = $_POST['name']

    $email = $_POST['email'];

    if ((strlen( $_POST['subject'] ) < 5) || (strlen( $_POST['message'] ) < 5))
    {
        die( 'Please fill in all fields!' );
    }
    else
    {
        $subject   = $_POST['subject'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
    }




    $mailheader  = "From: Your Site <noreply@" .$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']. ">\r\n";
    $mailheader .= "Reply-To: " .$name. "<" .$email. ">\r\n";
    $mailheader .= "Return-Path: noreply@" .$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']. "\r\n";
    $mailheader .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $mailheader .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
    $mailheader .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n";
    $mailheader .= "Message-ID: <" .time(). " noreply@" .$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']. ">\r\n";
    $mailheader .= "X-Mailer: PHP v" .phpversion(). "\r\n\r\n";


    if (@mail( $receiver, htmlspecialchars( $subject ), $message, $mailheader ))
    {

        echo 'Email send!';
    }
}

?>
```

HTML form:

```
<form action="mail.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
Email: <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
Subject: <input type="text" name="subject" /><br />
Message: <textarea name="message" cols="20" rows="2"></textarea><br />
<input name="send" type="submit" value="Send Email" />
</form>
```